# Change cell color in a column based on its value and if cell in another column is something specific

Tags: excel

I have a huge data file from a number of regression analyses, and in order to more easily read significant values (p<0.05) of certain variables I would like those cells to be in red.

Column A contains Apples, Pears and Oranges.
Column B contains their significance values.

I am only interested in the significant values of apples and pears, so even if the significance value of oranges is under 0.05 it shouldn't be in red. So the structure for the code should be:

"If Column A = Apples or Pears AND value in Column B < 0.05 then make the cell in Column B containing the value red".

I have tried to use conditional formatting but only managed to make all cells in column B with values < 0.05 red.
Would appreciate any help or direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with two conditional formatting rules.

First, select your pValue column and create a conditional format rule to set the cell to red if the value is less than 0.05. This will affect all the cells, not to worry.

[image: 1st format]

Next, select all your column data (in my case, a2 through b19), and create another conditional format rule. It's a rule based on a formula such as:

```
    =$A2="Orange"
```

and then **set the format to a white fill**, such as like this:

[image: 2nd format]

If it's not correctly working, make sure the formulas are in the correct order, like this, and that's it:

[image: final]

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes the whole data file so much easier to read, exactly what I was looking for :) I appreciate you taking the time

Comment: @hiwywh glad it worked. You could probably set the "stop if true" box too on that rule, but it appears it works even w/out flagging that box.